# cronjob not running in godaddy

Tags: python, cron

I have a Shared hosting in Godaddy, I run many php sites here.

Now I got a need to run a small python script as cron job , but unable to do that. Please help me.

**crontab -l**

```
* * * * * python /home/username/public_html/mysite.com/somefolder/croncheck.py
```

contents of my script **croncheck.py** , just writing date to a file.

```
import datetime

NOW = datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(0, 44999, 178350)
msg = str(NOW)+"\n"
with open("croncheck_output.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(msg)
```

I ran the following in shell to check my working or not. It executed, it added date to text file. But I am unable find the issue in running cronjob.

`python /home/username/public_html/mysite.com/somefolder/croncheck.py`

Comment: You are opening the file `croncheck_output.txt` in the current working directory, that will be where ever `cron` runs the application from (which we don't know where that is).

So in your Python script you should probably set a full path, or pass the path to the file in your execution from cron. Also, without any error messages, or knowing what is wrong we can't tell exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute paths for `python` interpreter (since `cron` usually runs with custom `PATH`):

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/username/public_html/mysite.com/somefolder/croncheck.py
```

Use absolute paths for opened file names in Python (since it's not obvious in which directory `cron` will run scripts):

```
import datetime

NOW = datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(0, 44999, 178350)
msg = str(NOW)+"\n"
with open("/tmp/croncheck_output.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(msg)
```

Check that user, from which `cron` runs script, has permission to write into output file.